# Microsoft Teams to ServiceNow Integration

Tags: jwt, servicenow, bearer-token, microsoft-teams

I am currently trying to integration Microsoft Teams and ServiceNow. I was able to send an HTTP Request to teams and create a connector card (through incoming web hook connector). This card has an actionable message that will perform the HttpPOST back to ServiceNow's processor path. In this processor, I was able to get the authorization header that contains the bearer token which as i understand is a JWT token. So below are my questions:

1) For security purposes, should I be verifying this JWT token? I tried to do this be it looks like I need a shared secret from MS Teams which I do not have.
2) Am i going about this correctly? Maybe i need to set up a bot in MS Teams that provides client ID and Secret and set up an OAuth in ServiceNow instead?

I really appreciate your inputs!

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [Security requirements for actionable messages in Office 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/security-requirements)

Here is C# sample code for [Token Validation](https://github.com/OfficeDev/outlook-actionable-messages-csharp-token-validation):

```
HttpRequestMessage request = this.ActionContext.Request;

    // Validate that we have a bearer token.
    if (request.Headers.Authorization == null ||
        !string.Equals(request.Headers.Authorization.Scheme, "bearer", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter))
    {
        return request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, new HttpError());
    }

    // Get the token from the Authorization header 
    string bearerToken = request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;

    ActionableMessageTokenValidator validator = new ActionableMessageTokenValidator();

    // This will validate that the token has been issued by Microsoft for the
    // specified target URL i.e. the target matches the intended audience (“aud” claim in token)
    // 
    // In your code, replace https://api.contoso.com with your service’s base URL.
    // For example, if the service target URL is https://api.xyz.com/finance/expense?id=1234,
    // then replace https://api.contoso.com with https://api.xyz.com
    ActionableMessageTokenValidationResult result = await validator.ValidateTokenAsync(bearerToken, "https://api.contoso.com");

    if (!result.ValidationSucceeded)
    {
        if (result.Exception != null)
        {
            Trace.TraceError(result.Exception.ToString());
        }

        return request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, new HttpError());
    }
```